# How do I ensure all Azure DevOps backlog items have a stack rank value?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I have an Azure DevOps board in the cloud configured to use a (modified) CMMI process.
I would like to export the tree of backlog items as CSV to another system, and I want to be able to replicate the exact order of the items.

Microsoft [explains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/backlogs-overview?view=azure-devops#backlog-priority-or-stack-rank-order) that:

> As you drag and drop items within the backlog list, a background
>   process  updates the Stack Rank (Agile and CMMI processes) or Backlog
>   Priority (Scrum  process) fields.

The Parent field helps me reconstruct the tree hierarchy.
But some of my items don't seem to have any value in the Stack Rank field, so I can't determine the correct order of sibling nodes.
In particular, it looks like items created as Epics and Features might be given a Stack Rank, but items created as Requirements or Tasks may not.
If I move items around, a Stack Rank value is assigned to the one that I moved, but not to its siblings.

How can I ensure that every item is given an appropriate Stack Rank value when it is created?

Or is there some operation I can do (preferably automatically via API) to add a Stack Rank to items that don't have one?

Comment: You can have a try with [workitem rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/custom-rules?view=azure-devops) or install extension WIT one click  (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mohitbagra.witoneclickactions) to create rules to automatically set the stack rank value when new work item is created. The problem is you have to specify a certain value for stack rank, it is not self-generated by system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this github issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/6866) response from @msebolt, Stack Rank isn't automatically assigned unless an item is re-ordered.

It seems that for items without a Stack Rank value, I can rely on the order of the items in the CSV export.

Comment: It is great that you solved it by referring to the order of the items. You can accept it as answer.